# Як правильно: наймач чи винаймач стосовно до помешкання?

Tags: вибір-слова, терміни, legal-terms

Зіткнувся з тим, що в юридичній практиці використовується ["наймач"](http://yurist-online.com/ukr/uslugi/yuristam/kodeks/003/816.php), а на "винаймач" посилань не можу навіть найти. Але мені здавалось, що найняти можна на роботу, наприклад, тобто людину, а будівлю можна [винаймати](http://sum.in.ua/s/vynajmaty). Але навіть у останньому прикладі термін пояснюється через [наймати](http://sum.in.ua/s/najmaty). Це нові правила введені в юридичних документах, чи я просто помиляюсь?

Comment: До речі, чув, що квартплату колись називати *комірним*

Comment: Мені також звично, що «наймач» — це той, хто наймає на роботу. Судячи з тлумачного словника, це універсальне слово. А той, хто винаймає помешкання, для мене завжди був «орендар». «Винаймач» особисто я ніколи не чув, хоч воно існує. Можливо, воно не дуже розповсюджене. Передивився всі свої двомовні словники — немає в них «винаймати». Проте трапляєтся «знімати» у тому ж значенні.

Comment: На мою думку "орендар" найкращий варіант.

Answer (score 4):

Перш за все, традиційно звертаємось до Словника української мови в 11 томах (1970–1980).

Окрім того, що, як правильно зазначив автор запитання, ***`винаймати`*** тлумачиться через ***`наймати`***, слід звернути увагу на позначку *`діал.`* до цього слова.

> [ВИНАЙМА́ТИ](http://sum.in.ua/s/vynajmaty), аю, аєш, недок.,
>   ВИ́НАЙМИТИ, млю, миш; мн. ви́наймлять; і ВИ́НАЙНЯТИ, йму, ймеш, док.,
>   перех., діал. **Наймати що-небудь, орендувати.** *Винаймали
>   [зарібники] собі поле й ходили на роботу* (Ольга Кобилянська, II,
>   1956, 29); *У двох товаришів, що винаймали окрему хату, сходився..
>   таємний кружок* (Осип Маковей, Вибр., 1954, 57); *З початком літа
>   винаймив Василь для «своїх» човен на ставі* (Ірина Вільде, На порозі,
>   1955, 59); *Винайняв [Степан] двадцять два морги поля й обробляє його*
>   (Антін Крушельницький, Буденний хліб.., 1960, 47).

Діалектичність додатково підтверджується  статтею до іменника ***`винайм`***.

> [ВИНА́ЙМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/vynajm), у, чол., діал. **Дія за
>   значенням *`винаймати`***. *Заки священник полагодив з громадою
>   формальності винайму дяківки [дякової хати] на школу, почалася
>   ..осінь* (Уляна Кравченко, Вибр., 1958, 389).

Слова [винаймач](http://sum.in.ua/s/vynajmach) у СУМ не знайдено.

Дієслово ***`наймати`***, хоч охоплює більше значень, але з-поміж інших, має й значення, що нас цікавить, до того ж без будь-якого стилістичного забарвлення:

> [НАЙМАТИ](http://sum.in.ua/s/najmaty), аю, аєш, недок., НАЙНЯТИ,
>   найму, наймеш, док., перех. і без додатка.
>
> 2. **Брати для користування що-небудь за плату на певний час**. *З осені він безпремінно наймає десятин з п'ятнадцять, а то і всі
>      двадцять поля* (Панас Мирний, IV, 1955, 212); *Мати наймала щороку
>      грядку на городину* (Степан Васильченко, IV, 1960, 10); *— Оце я тут
>      живу, — сказала Погана. — Кімнату наймаю в однієї вдови-офіцерші*
>      (Олесь Гончар, II, 1959, 245); Крижицький.. *у заможнішого господаря
>      наймав збиту з дощок комірку з віконцем поверх дверей* (Степан
>      Чорнобривець, Визволена земля, 1959, 158); *Галя раніш жила у
>      свекрухи, тепер же найняла собі домівку* (Леся Українка, V, 1956,
>      125); *Я пройшов по мокрому пероні, Дихаючи повними грудьми, І найняв
>      підводу* (Максим Рильський, II, 1960, 15).

Той, хто наймає, відповідно - ***`наймач`***.

> [НАЙМА́Ч](http://sum.in.ua/s/najmach), а, чол. **Той, хто наймає
>   кого-, що-небудь**. *— Може б, трапився якийсь наймач та взяв мене на
>   службу до себе* (Нечуй-Левицький, IV, 1956, 284); *Виникають у степу
>   батраки. Ось їх величезні юрби біля берега Дніпра.. Чекають наймача*
>   (Олександр Довженко, Зачарована Десна, 1957, 517).

Синоніми до ***`наймати`*** і ***`наймач`*** - ***`орендувати`*** й ***`орендар`*** відповідно.

> [ОРЕНДУВАТИ](http://sum.in.ua/s/orenduvaty), ую, уєш, недок., перех.
>   **Брати в оренду; користуватися тим, що взяте в оренду.** *Забродівчани орендують біля Дніпра ділянку лугу, що належить лісництву* (Юрій Мокрієв, Слід.., 1969, 10); *Корчма належала вже
>   староству Даніловича, і її орендував спритний шинкар аж десь із-під
>   Жовкви* (Іван Ле, Хмельницький, I, 1957, 7).
>
> [ОРЕНДА́Р](http://sum.in.ua/s/orendar), я, чол.
>   1. **Той, хто орендує що-небудь**.  *До гурту підійшов орендар вербівського млина, досить ще молодий Нухим Абрамович* (Арсен Іщук,
>   Вербівчани, 1961, 24).

Ймовірно, цією логікою й керувалися законодавці.

Так, у [Цивільному кодексі України](http://search.ligazakon.ua/l_doc2.nsf/link1/T030435.html) є **Глава 58. Найм (оренда)**, яка встановлює правила щодо договірних відносин найму майна різних видів, в тому числі й помешкання. Зокрема, термін ***`наймач`*** вживається 147 разів у тексті кодексу, на відміну від слова ***`винаймач`***, що не зустрічається взагалі.

Answer (score 0):

Правильним варіантом буде слово "наймач", крім наведених прикладів, звернімося до [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87):

> **Наймач** — фізична або юридична особа, яка за договором найму (оренди)
>   приймає майно у користування за плату на певний строк.

Тако з тієї ж Вікіпедії отримуємо посилання на СУМ та на ще один варіант (однак врахуйте, що він вважається застарілим) - "**[посесор](http://sum.in.ua/s/posesor)**" (а також, швидше за все - це калька віл англійського "possess" (володіти).

А також заглянемо в [Тлумачний словник](https://classes.ru/all-ukrainian/dictionary-ukrainian-explanatory-term-91532.htm), де бачимо, що "наймач" це:

> 3) Те саме, що орендар.

Answer (score 0):

У «Словнику української мови» в 11 томах (1974) бачимо лише слова *[найма́ч](http://sum.in.ua/s/najmach)* і *[найма́чка](http://sum.in.ua/s/najmachka)*, причому, здається, в іншому значенні: «той, хто наймає кого-, що-небудь».

Але в пізніших словниках:

- У слів *найма́ч* і *наймачка* явно з'являється потрібне значення:

  «Великий тлумачний словник сучасної української мови» (2001):

  > **[найма́ч](//www.lingvolive.com/en-us/translate/uk-uk/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87)**
  >
  > -а, ч.
  >
  > 1) Той, хто наймає кого-, що-небудь.
  >
  > 2) Сторона договору найму жилого приміщення, яка отримує від іншої сторони (наймодавця) жиле приміщення за плату для проживання у ньому.
  >
  > 3) Те саме, що [орендар](//www.lingvolive.com/en-us/translate/uk-uk/%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80).
  >
  > ---
  >
  > **[найма́чка](//www.lingvolive.com/en-us/translate/uk-uk/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0)**
  >
  > -и
  >
  > Жін. до [наймач](//www.lingvolive.com/en-us/translate/uk-uk/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87).
- Явно з'являються слова *винайма́ч*, *винайма́чка*:

  «Словник Української мови» у 20 томах (2012):

  > **[ВИНАЙМА́Ч](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=189778&page=337)**, а́, *ч*. *Той, хто щось винаймає, орендує що-небудь. На порозі стояв у халаті й домашній шапочці власник будинку. Незважаючи на мороз, перебіг подвір'я і завітав до винаймачів* (Ю. Хорунжий); *У ХІХ сторіччі в містах набули поширення будинки і квартири, які за платню здавали винаймачам* (з навч. літ.).
  >
  > ---
  >
  > **[ВИНАЙМА́ЧКА](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=189779&page=337)**, и, *ж*. Жін. до **винайма́ч**. *Відмова винаймачки оплачувати комунальні послуги у зв'язку з постійними перебоями бойлерної станції стала причиною її виселення з помешкання* (з газ.); *На кухні виникла сварка між винаймачкою житла і хазяйкою* (з Інтернету).

  «Великий тлумачний словник сучасної української мови» (2001):

  > **[винайма́ч](//www.lingvolive.com/en-us/translate/uk-uk/%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87)**
  >
  > -а, ч.
  >
  > Той, хто щось орендує.
  >
  > ---
  >
  > **[винайма́чка](//www.lingvolive.com/en-us/translate/uk-uk/%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0)**
  >
  > -и
  >
  > Жін. до [винаймач](//www.lingvolive.com/en-us/translate/uk-uk/%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87).

Також, як уже частково [казали](/a/4712), ще є слова:

- *[оренда́р](http://sum.in.ua/s/orendar)*, *[оренда́рка](http://sum.in.ua/s/orendarka)* (а також розмовні і рідковживані *[оренда́тор](http://sum.in.ua/s/orendator)*, *[оренда́торка](http://sum.in.ua/s/orendatorka)*);
- застаріле *[посе́сор](http://sum.in.ua/s/posesor)*.